# KMM throw Mismatched @Composable annotation between expect and actual declaration when composeCompilerVersion is 1.5.0

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform

agpVersion=8.1.0-rc01

composeCompilerVersion=1.5.0-dev-k1.9.0-6a60475e07f

kotlinVersion=1.9.0

kspVersion=1.9.0-1.0.11

My KMM (Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile) project recently upgraded Kotlin to 1.9.0 and updated the Compose Compiler to 1.5.0-dev, and it's throwing a mismatch exception.

`Mismatched @Composable annotation between expect and actual declaration`

However, the same code works without any issues in Kotlin 1.8.21 and Compose 1.4.8, as the @Composable annotation is only needed for use in Android.

**common:**

```
interface IssueFixClass {
}
//no arg
expect class IssueFixNoneClass  private constructor(content: () -> Unit):IssueFixClass {
    fun invoke()
    companion object Delegate{
        fun makeClass(content: () -> Unit):IssueFixNoneClass
    }
}
```

**androidMain:**

```
actual class IssueFixNoneClass private actual constructor(private val content:@Composable @UiComposable ()->Unit):IssueFixClass{

    @SuppressLint("ComposableNaming")
    @Composable
    @UiComposable
    actual fun invoke(){
        content.invoke()
    }
    actual companion object Delegate{
        actual fun makeClass(content: @Composable @UiComposable () -> Unit):IssueFixNoneClass{
          return  IssueFixNoneClass(content)
        }
    }
}
```

**iosMain:**

```
actual class IssueFixNoneClass private actual constructor(private val content: () -> Unit):IssueFixClass {
    actual fun invoke() {
        content.invoke()
    }

    actual companion object Delegate {
        actual fun makeClass(content: () -> Unit): IssueFixNoneClass {
            return IssueFixNoneClass(content)
        }
    }
}
```

I just want the program to compile correctly.

Comment: StackOverflow is not an issue tracker. If your code works in one version, and doesn't work in an other one, especially in non released one, which 1.5.0 is ATM, you should [report](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/new?component=612128) it to the maintainers

Answer (score 1):

Just add `@Composable` annotation to expect class and it is OK.